# Insert d3 select body tags between document.write divs

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am new to d3 and html and I want to have the html tags I generate with d3 appear inside div tags that I create with document write.

Here is what I mean:

```
<div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
<h2>Column 1</h2>
// tags generated from d3 here 
</div>
```

right now what I have written looks something like this:

```
document.write("<div class=\"column\" style=\"background-color:#aaa;\">")
document.write("<h2>Column 1</h2>")

d3.select("body")
    .selectAll("p")
    .data(myData)
    .enter()
    .append("p")
    //a bunch of stuff
    document.write("</div>")
```

but unfortunately this generates

```
<div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
<h2>Column 1</h2></div>
//tags generated by d3
```

which is not what I want at all

ps. it's probably not important but all of the javascript is wrapped in

```
d3.csv(dataPath, function (error, data){ })
```

Comment: `d3.select(".column").selectAll("p").etc...` Also, why are you using `document.write`? You can manipulate the DOM the way you want with D3 only.

Comment: thank you that works! I'm using documentgetElementbyId now, I know I can manipulate the dom with d3 but my n00b levels just made be stick with what I know where I can!  (not the best strategy I know)